# Mongoid caseinsensitive query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, indexing, mongoid, denormalization

I want to make a case insensitive mongoid query on a mission title.

Lets say the model looks like:

```
class Mission
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title
  filed :description
end
```

Can this be accomplished with a mongoid scope/index and what would it look like?

Also, Is better practice to denormalize the data and hold a indexable lowercase field and if so what would that look like?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is currently a ticket open to support case insensitive indexes. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a field you will be indexing the best solution is to add an additional field which holds an lower/upper case version of your field as suggested [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90).

If not, you can [query by a case insensitive regex](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions). This will have performance impacts however so tred lightly.

```
db.Mission.find({"title" : /foo/i})
```